# How to copy cell value based on the given Date in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I attached my table. I want to get date(In inputbox) from Column A and D 
and copy the adjacent cell value (Column B and E). Then paste in different cell.

For eg. if i enter date 15.10.2016 and 25.10.2017. Then output must be as shown in figure. If the date is not present in the column then Msgbox as invalid date. Help me

[image]

Comment: Please post your code. These vidoes may help: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) and [Excel VBA Introduction Part 11.1 - Input Boxes](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=d07yuwGHZpo&index=11&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5)

Comment: It sounds like you have an idea of the elements required. Why not share what you have tried? If you haven't written anything, then write something and share. In both cases, state what problems you have encountered.

Answer (score 0):

This quick method would work for you.

```
Sub get_money()
        a_col_last_row = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        d_col_last_row = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        data_a = InputBox("Enter 1st date")
        data_d = InputBox("Enter 2st date")
        lookup_val_a = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(3, 8)
        Dim refRng_a As Range
        Dim refRng_d As Range
        Set refRng_a = Range("A2:B" & a_col_last_row)
        'data_a = Cells(3, 8).Value
        Set refRng_d = Range("D2:E" & d_col_last_row)
        'data_d = Cells(3, 9).Value
        On Error GoTo errhandler1:
        Cells(3, 8) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(data_a, refRng_a, 2, 0)
controlback:
        On Error GoTo errhandler2:
        Cells(3, 9) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(data_d, refRng_d, 2, 0)

        End
errhandler1:
        MsgBox "1st Value not found"
        Err.Number = 0
        Resume controlback

errhandler2:
        MsgBox " 2nd Value not found"
        Err.Number = 0
End Sub
```

However please note that I have used the same Range (H3, I3) for input as well as output. I thought you want it that way. You may change it according to your need.

Comment: I need an inputbox to get the date.

Comment: Edited the answer to fit your needs. :) @Deepak